# Unset variable in robot framework

Tags: robotframework

I'm using RF keyword "Set Suite Variable" for setting up session variable. Is there any way how to **unset** this variable?

After "unsetting" the variable it should be possible run keyword "variable should not exist" successfully.

Example:

```
*** Test Cases ***
Test Case One
    ${session}=    Create session
    Set Suite Variable    ${session}

Test Case Two
    Close Session    ${session}
    Unset Variable    ${session}
    Variable Should Not Exists    ${session}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to unset a robot variable. The closest approximation is to set it to `${None}` and check for that rather than checking for existence.

Answer (score 0):

One workaround will be to note down all test variables & make a function to reset them all. Sounds silly, but it may work.